# Ember-data with Node.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is two part question -

a) While trying to configure Ember-data to retrieve records from Node.js, we are running into issues while retrieving nested objects

let's say we have

```
Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title:DS.attr('string'),
  comments:DS.hasMany('Comment'),
  tags:DS.hasMany('Tag')
});

Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  tag:DS.attr('string'),
  posts:DS.hasMany('Post')
});

Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  post:DS.belongsTo('Post'),
  text:DS.attr('string')
});
```

the URL request for post looks like 'api/posts/:post_id?'

What do we do to make comments URL look like 'api/posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id?'

b) in a many to many relationship, like tag<->post, the url for tags should look just like the url for posts: 'api/posts/:post_id?'

```
'api/tags/:tag_id?'
```

Note: '?' after :xxx_id means xxx_id is optional